# What is best approach to create 100+ stores in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multicurrency, multi-website

Magento CE 1.9.x
Assume the case that we need to create 100+ stores having 10k products in each store.

1. each store will have 100+ products.
2. there are very high chances that each store can have their own root categories.
3. some products can be unavailable in certain stores.
4. language can vary across two stores (within the same Magento instance)
5. currency may also vary if between two stores.
6. product quantity may also vary between two stores and price too.

In this approach what will be the best method to be used?

1. create a separate website for each 100+ stores (i.e 100 stores + 100 website + 100 store view )
2. keep one main domain (website) and create 100+ stores and stores view. (i.e 100 stores + 1 website + 100 store view )

Base currency may be same or different both and language also may be same or different both.

For example 15/100 store is in India , at different states. So base currency will be INR for those 15 stores. Prices also may vary , depend on the state or city in which store resides.(example taxes are different so price may vary). Rest 85/100 stores may be divided on other parts of world like USA (dollars base currency , language en_US) , Singapore ( Singapore dollar base currency , language en_US) , UK (base currency euro , language en_UK )

I heard that creating multiple websites may cause system performance issues. Please advice if this is true.

Comment: Base currency, customer base, and prices will these be same or different?

Comment: Base currency may be same or different both.

Comment: Base currency may be same or different both. For example 15/100 store is in India , at different states. So base currency will be INR for those 15 stores. Prices also may vary , depend on the state or city in which store resides.(example taxes are different so price may vary). Rest 85/100 stores may be divided on other parts of world like USA (dollars base currency , language en_US) , Singapore ( Singapore dollar base currency , language en_US) , UK (base currency euro , language en_UK )

Answer (score 1):

As you have requirement of different base currencies you will have to go for multi website. Below are the options which will be provided by multi website:-

- different prices
- different tax classes
- different (base) currencies
- different payment options
- different shipping options

You can have different customer base for all website. But it will upto you.

Primary use of multi store is if you want individual theme, or language.

You can review this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156151/magento-2-1-3-multi-website-or-multi-store) And review the Answer by Raphael

Similarly this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7393/difference-between-website-stores-and-store-views/175809) have useful information for you before you start the project.

So basically -

> Website is the top-level container for sites, shipping methods,
>   payment methods, and so on. To create completely separate sites that
>   do not share cart, shipping methods, and so on, you must create
>   separate websites.
>
> Store is contained by a website . In turn, a store contains at least
>   one store view.
>
> Multiple stores can share cart, user sessions, payment gateways, and
>   so on, but they have separate catalog structures.
>
> Store views change the way pages are presented, and are typically used
>   to display a store with different layouts or languages.

Reference taken from [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html) (Magento2.2 ver)

Hope the answer help you.

Comment: Thanks @LAW for your feedback for creating multiple website. (Which suits the curent scope and scenario mentioned). However I am not sure about the performance of site. How the database size or performance will affect . If I create 1 website + 100 stores (100 store view) VS 100 website + 100 stores + 100 store view. After creating websites I am sure I will get more flexibility. What about loading time and performance.

Comment: I believe the performance should basically be dependent on the server configuration and the load on that very instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes no need to create separate website.
create store on the basis of Root category and just create different view for this store.
for example:

website->Store(root category: Default Category)-> UAE(en_uae)

website->Store(root category: Default Category)-> USA(en_usa)

website->Store(root category: Default Category)-> UK(en_uk)

-> you need to create store on the basis of category

-> you need to create view on the basis of language

Comment: Suppose if my all 50 store belongs to USA(en_usa) , how is that possible ?

Comment: then on which base you want to differentiate them ?

Comment: Base currency may be same or different both. For example 15/100 store is in India , at different states. So base currency will be INR for those 15 stores. Prices also may vary , depend on the state or city in which store resides.(example taxes are different so price may vary). Rest 85/100 stores may be divided on other parts of world like USA (dollars base currency , language en_US) , Singapore ( Singapore dollar base currency , language en_US) , UK (base currency euro , language en_UK )

Comment: For different country/language  you need to create separate view for it simple.
For different price on the basis of tax you need to set Tax rate instead to create new view.
Done create useless views.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend to use Magento2 for multi-store development. Here are few of the reasons why.

https://www.cminds.com/move-magento-2/

This is an old video, but still helpful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=talXT161vnM

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions . This is not at all possible in Magento CE 1.9.X ?  I heard some paid module available but not sure it will affect the core functionality or affect on other inbuilt modules.

Comment: Multi-store is definitely possible with 1.9.x. However, end of life of 1.9 is pretty soon. Since PHP is moving fast, everybody has to move along with PHP. You might need to upgrade 1.9 to 2.x sooner than you thought. To avoid the painful upgrade, it's a better idea to start with 2.x. I'm assuming it's a new build.